# Rewriting the product resource collection doesn't take effect on tag product collection

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides

I need to add a method to the collections of products in magento, the base model which seems to be the parent of all the collections (e.g. `Mage_Tag_Model_Resource_Product_Collection`) is

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
```

I rewrote this collection and added the methods I needed like:

```
class Mycompany_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection extends
Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
{
  public function sortBySalesTimesProfitTimesCommission(){
    //blah blah blah
  }
}
```

And including the `xml` configs it works. But now, when I use the collection in the **tag page** it is of the type

```
Mage_Tag_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
```

Which inherits from the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection`. and the parent is not rewritten.

Is there any way to rewrite the parent? Or any other approach which doesn't make me copy the method `sortBySalesTimesProfitTimesCommission` and keep it unique in the code to avoid breaking the DRY principle?